# Gettin "Accepted" reply for every single sent message on Twilio Whatsapp API

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using Twilio Whatsapp API with Integromat. Both on Sandbox and the Whatsapp number Twilio gave me, I always recieve a reply saying "Accepted" for every message I send to these numbers. After that reply, I get the replies from my bot. So, the API is working OK, but I always recieve this "Accepted" message...

Does anybody know how to disbale it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integromat by default responds to any webhook with a 200 code and the body "Accepted". In order to change this, you need to create a new moudele right after the first Webhook module, called "Webhook response". On "Status" insert the value "204" and left the "Body" blank.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio doesn't return a message via WhatsApp saying "Accepted". Can you duplicate this behavior outside Integromat, by [calling the API directly](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio-Beta-)?

Comment: I don't know hot to duplicate this behavior calling the API directly, because it happens when my Twilio numbers recieve a message. But if I left the WHEN A MESSAGE COMES IN endpoint blank, I don't get this "Acceped" message when I send a message tot he number.

I attach a screenshot of how this message looks like on the Twilio's Console log: https://i.ibb.co/M2bN1Hd/joder.jpg

Comment: Are sure the WhatsApp end-point you are sending to isn't responding with Accepted?

Comment: Ok, you were right.

Integromat by default responds to any webhook with a 200 code and the body "Accepted". In order to change this, you need to create a new moudele right after the first Webhook module, called "Webhook response". On "Status" insert the value "204" and left the "Body" blank.

Thanks for the help @alan!